# Custom key for grouping in Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I want to be able to use grouping via a custom key but here is my attempt so far ,

We used custom classes for the keys of KV objects because we want to GroupBy with a more complicated condition rather than simple key matching using String etc.

````
```

    PCollection<KV<Multikey, Iterable<SomeObject>> pc2 = 
    pc.apply(GroupByKey.<Multikey, SomeObject>create());

```
````

Express the match condition with the equals method.

````
```
    class Multikey implements Serializable{

        List<String> keys = new ArrayList<>();  //multiple key

        ......
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object k){
            ...join conditions
        }
    }

```
````

But I get an error.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: the keyCoder of a GroupByKey must be deterministic
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.GroupByKey.expand(GroupByKey.java:193)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.GroupByKey.expand(GroupByKey.java:107)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyInternal(Pipeline.java:537)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyTransform(Pipeline.java:471)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection.apply(PCollection.java:357)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:282)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.Coder$NonDeterministicException: org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.SerializableCoder@18b411b5 is not deterministic because:
    Java Serialization may be non-deterministic.
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.SerializableCoder.verifyDeterministic(SerializableCoder.java:205)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.GroupByKey.expand(GroupByKey.java:191)
```

It seems that the order in which "keys" is serialized is wrong, so I implemented a custom serializer or tried various coders, but didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Please note the [GroupByKey documentation](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.0.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/GroupByKey.html):

> Two keys of type K are compared for equality not by regular Java Object.equals(java.lang.Object), but instead by first encoding each of the keys using the Coder of the keys of the input PCollection, and then comparing the encoded bytes. This admits efficient parallel evaluation. Note that this requires that the Coder of the keys be deterministic (see Coder.verifyDeterministic()). If the key Coder is not deterministic, an exception is thrown at pipeline construction time.

One possible approach: use a pardo which outputs KVs, output the value with a unique key as a string, based on the complicated conditional logic you mentioned.

The other approach is to use a custom object type for your key instead of a string, as you have tried so far. You'll need to implement a [CustomCoder](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.0.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/coders/CustomCoder.html) which is byte equivalent for two of your Objects which represent the same key.

Here is the Apache Beam documentation on [specifying coders](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#specifying-coders).

Here is a blog post with a few custom coder [examples as well](https://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-beam/coders-apache-beam/read).

Also, Re: The exception itself. See verifyDeterministic docs to see the [description of a deterministic coder](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.0.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/coders/Coder.html#verifyDeterministic--). It is likely you have violated this constranit.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. I read the document.

I will explain why I want to use custom keys.

That's because we want to express a disjunction like "or", not a normal combination.

```
    class Multikey implements Serializable
        List <String> keys = new ArrayList <> ();

........

        @Override
        public boolean equals (Object k) {
            if (k instanceof Multikey) {
                List <String> ky = new ArrayList <String> (((Multikey) k) .keys);
                // Representation of disjunction
                ky.retainAll (keys);
                return! ky.isEmpty ();

            } else {
                return false;
            }
    }
```

I read the document, but it seems that GroupBy's key needs to be a single deterministic value.
Is it difficult to express disjunction in grouping?

Comment: Yes, everything must be assigned to a key. If you want to assign an element to multiple keys, then you must output the element twice, with a separate key.